# In a WPF ListView how can I prevent auto scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, scroll

I have a WPF ListView which currently scrolls everytime I click on an item which is only partially visible.  How can I keep the control from scrolling that item into view (instead simply selecting the partially visible one)?  This behavior is very annoying when doing a drag from this control.

Thanks.

Added:  I am looking for a solution to keep the control itself from scrolling when contents are clicked that the control believes are not fully visible.  Often this is by a few pixels and the scroll is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The items scroll into view because the default behavior on list item click is to call BringIntoView().  You can add an event handler for the RequestBringIntoView event and catch it before it bubbles up from the ListViewItems to the ScrollViewer.  In your handler, check the bounds of the sender against the visible region and if you decide that you don't need to scroll, set the event's Handled flag to true.

Comment: To clarify, use the PreviewMouseDown event to swallow it.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm currently on the road, I cannot try this, but have you tried playing around with CanContentScroll, and/or wrapping the scrollable content into a Panel, as suggested by the [ScrollViewer Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx)?

In the worst case, you might want to replace the `ListView`'s [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) by a hacked ScrollViewer with a "fuzz" factor, e.g. by capturing the [`RequestBringIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.requestbringintoview.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [this approach](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggableListView.aspx)?

just as an addon, I don't know how much you know about the subject, but [here is a good place](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ListViewDragDropManager.aspx) to read more about it.

added:

I just found that you can [prevent the mouse wheel of scrolling](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/09/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from.html) as well.