# Avoid scrolling following the focus on MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scroll, itemscontrol

I have the following `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Model.XList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

On each of them applies the following template:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:MyModelType}">
    <Border MaxWidth="140">
        <local:SingleView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Actually makes each of them to "SingleView" control.**

The ItemsControl wrapped in `ScrollViewer`.

When I have a large number of items (the scroll seems), and I press any button of the controls, the screen jumps (probably because the scroll getting the focus has changed).

I want to avoid scrolling following the focus.

I've seen solutions that make it through the Code-Behind, by `RequestBringIntoView` event.

But I'm working with **`MVVM`**, does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: `I've seen solutions that make it through the Code-Behind, by RequestBringIntoView event.` - can you show this solution?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209416/in-a-wpf-listview-how-can-i-prevent-auto-scrolling

Comment: Have you tried `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` for `ItemsControl`? And have you seen [`this`](http://serialseb.blogspot.ru/2007/09/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from.html) method? This method fits under MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What helped me is to avoid receiving focus on `ItemsControl`**

(if there's a wrapper to ItemsControl so you can avoid getting focus also there)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Model.XList}" Focusable="False">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```